# Spark SQL- Running Query in HiveContext vs DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm exploring Spark SQL and I've been experimenting with Hive Query Language (HQL) and DataFrames. Some time ago, I performed an experiment comparing the performance of running queries via HiveContext versus that of DataFrames.

I ran a query in a loop

```
for(i <- 1 to 100){
  val selectQuery : String = s"SELECT * FROM table_1 t1 JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table_3 t3 ON (t1.col1 = t3.col1 and t2.col2 = t3.col2) WHERE t1.col2 = $i"

  hiveContext.sql(s"INSERT INTO resultTable PARTITION(col_res = $i) $selectQuery")
}
```

It ran for about 4 hours.

Then I loaded the tables in DataFrames and wrote it in the result table

```
val t1 = hiveContext.sql("SELECT * FROM table_1")
val t2 = hiveContext.sql("SELECT * FROM table_2")
val t3 = hiveContext.sql("SELECT * FROM table_3")

for(i <- 1 to 100){
  val resultDF = t1.filter(s"col2 === $i").join(t2, "col1").join(t3, Seq("col1", "col2"), "left_outer")

  resultDF.write.mode("append").format("parquet").partitionBy("").saveAsTable(resultTable)
}
```

Which ran for only an hour and a half (I did not cache or persist the DataFrames).

Initially, I thought that in the first way, map/reduce jobs were run because I ran the query through HiveContext in Hive but apparently, this assumption was wrong.

My current theory is that HiveContext has to connect to Hive 100 times in the loop and that's what makes the first method consume so much time.

I've scoured the net looking for the reason behind this difference but haven't found anything yet. Could someone help shed some light on this? I use Spark 1.5.0

PS- The query is just for demonstration. I don't know whether it'll actually work. Please let me know if any more information is required.

**Edit** This question is about an actual difference observed in code. My question isn't *if* there will be a difference in time taken for execution. My question is *why* there was a difference in this particular scenario.